# Web page caching using Ehcache

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, html, ehcache

I am trying to make my web application faster by using caching of web pages for faster access next time so can anyone provide me guideline how to use Ehcache for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ehcache documentation on [web caching](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/modules/web-caching.html) should be a good start. For a quick start they also have a [code sample / recipe](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/recipes/pagecaching.html) on that.

EDIT: (how to see if it's working)

1. enable logging for package `net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter` (e.g. `DEBUG` level) and look at the log entries
2. `SimplePageCachingFilter` is gzipping the response; look for `Content-Encoding: gzip` in HTTP response headers - `Content-Length` should be smaller than before
3. `ehcache.xml`: configure cache to `overflowToDisk="true"` and set `<diskStore path="target/ehcache-diskStore"/>` - a (at first empty) file named `SimplePageCachingFilter.data` should have been created there
4. JMX / cache statistics (more complicated; see [JMX-Tutorial](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/operations/jmx.html))
5. ...

Comment: Hi thanx for your reply I have tried code sample / recipe in which i have added filter and filter mapping for simplepagecaching filter in web.xml and provided ehcache.xml in   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:ehcache.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param> it gives error at the time of deploy which is :  net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: cache 'SimplePageCachingFilter' not found in configuration

Comment: I got it solved by specifying cache with name simplePageCachingFilter in ehcache.xml but now i dont know how to know is any caching is done or not? how can i come to know the caching is done ?

Comment: my application deployed successfully but i dot getting cache benefit do anyone know how to get this worked?

Comment: @HemantMetalia: I updated my answer on how to see if it's working. What exactly do you mean by "no cache benefit"?